# Baby Rudin Theorem 2.33

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Theorem 2.33
Suppose $K \subset Y \subset X$. Then $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

I understand the first part of the proof: if $K$ is compact relative to $X$ then $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

However, the proof of the converse statement confuses me.

Proof given:
Conversely, suppose $K$ is compact relative to $Y$, let ${G_\alpha}$ be a collection of open subsets of $X$ which covers $K$, and put $V_\alpha = Y \cap G_\alpha$. Then $K \subset V_{\alpha_{1}} \cup ... \cup V_{\alpha_{n}}$ will hold for some choice of $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$; and since $V_\alpha \subset G_\alpha$, $K \subset V_{\alpha_{1}} \cup ... \cup V_{\alpha_{n}}$ implies $K \subset G_{\alpha_{1}} \cup ... \cup G_{\alpha_{n}}$.

My question:
What is the purpose of introducing $V_\alpha$? Is it to show that $V_\alpha \in Y$ so that we can prove that $K$ is compact relative to $Y$?

Comment: The topology of $Y$ consists of intersections of $Y$ with open sets of $X$. That $K$ is compact relative to $Y$ means the definition of compact, but using the topology of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I missed out the concept that to prove K is compact relative to X, we need to show that $G_\alpha$ is finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this proof, you are not trying to *prove* that $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

Instead, you are *assuming* that $K$ is compact relative to $Y$, and you want to use that assumption to prove that $K$ is compact relative to $X$.

You've started off correctly: to prove $K$ is compact relative to $X$, you start by choosing $G_\alpha$ to be a collection of open subsets of $X$ which covers $K$.

Now comes the question: How do you identify a finite number of the $G_\alpha$ which still covers $K$?

There's really only one thing to try, namely to somehow use the knowledge that $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

Question: How shall you use that knowledge?

Answer: Take the intersection of each $G_\alpha$ with $Y$.

What you get is a collection of sets $V_\alpha = Y \cap G_\alpha$.

And now put together what you know about the sets $V_\alpha$: (1) You know that the $V_\alpha$ sets cover $Y$; and (2) You know that the $V_\alpha$ sets are open relative to $Y$.

Applying the knowledge that $K$ is compact relative to $Y$, you may conclude that there exist $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ such that $K \subset V_{\alpha_1} \cup\cdots\cup V_{\alpha_n}$, and the proof is completed as you wrote it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more formal:

0) $K \subset Y \subset X$;

Show that: If $K$ is compact in $Y$ then $K$ is compact in $X$.

1) Consider an open  cover of $K$ in $X$, i.e.

$K \subset \bigcup G_{\alpha}$, $G_{\alpha} \subset X$, open in $X$.

2) $V_{\alpha}:= G_{\alpha} \cap Y$ is open in $Y$.

3) $K \subset \bigcup V_{\alpha}$ (why?).

4)Since $K$ is compact in $Y$ there is a finite subcover

$K \subset  V_{\alpha_1}\cup V_{\alpha_2} \cup...\cup V_{\alpha_n}$.

5) $V_{\alpha_i} \subset G_{\alpha_i}$ , $i=1,2,..,n$,

$K \subset \bigcup G_{\alpha_i}$, $i=1,2,..n$, a finite subcover of $\bigcup G_{\alpha}$, and we are done.

Note:

3') $K= K \cap Y \subset (\bigcup G _{\alpha}) \cap Y$.

$K \subset \bigcup (G_{\alpha} \cap Y)$(Distributive law).